# How to avoid one element being greater than another when using mb_substr php

Tags: php, html, css

At the moment I use mb_substr at `0 - 300` characters in the first part, and `300` onward for the collapse. The main issue I'm having is that when people use more breaks or different formatting the div element becomes way larger.

I want it to be able to have equal sizing, even when having a different format (i.e more line breaks). At the moment I'm unsure if this is a formatting problem with html and css, or if this is a PHP problem. Is there a way to achieve this?

html

```html
<div class="server-main">
   @if (strlen($server->description) >= 300) 
       {!! nl2br(mb_substr(html_entity_decode($server->description), 0, 300)) !!}
          <div class="collapse" id="collapse{{$server->id}}">
                {!! nl2br(mb_substr(html_entity_decode($server->description), 300)) !!}
           </div>
           <div class="button-containter" style="text-align-center; margin: auto; padding-top: 20px;">
              <button type="button" style="color: white;" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{$server->id}}">Show more</button>
            </div><br>              
   @else
      {!! nl2br($server->description) !!}
   @endif
</div>
```

css

```css
.server-main {
    margin: 10px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    font-size: 11px;
    }
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my english.

Since your div height will be variable, you need to add it in a row div. The row div will be fixed for your height, while the height of the div will vary accordingly.

like this,

```
 <div class="main"> <div class=“server-main">@if (strlen($server->description) >= 300)!! nl2br(mb_substr(html_entity_decode($server->description), 0, 300)) !!}<div class="collapse" id="collapse{{$server->id}}">{!! nl2br(mb_substr(html_entity_decode($server->description), 300)) !!}</div><div class="button-containter" style="text-align-center; margin: auto; padding-top: 20px;"><button type="button" style="color: white;" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=“#collapse{{$server->id}}">Show more</button></div><br>else{!! nl2br($server->description) !!}@endif</div></div>
```

sorry for code, i am newbee.

then css is

```
.main {
   you can add here, margin, padding, vs.
}
.server-main {
margin: 10px;
min-height: %100;
padding: 10px;
min-height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
word-wrap: break-word;
margin-bottom:0px;
font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this didnt fix the problem. Yes, it doesn't expand but you want see the content that goes out of the div